# How can I change my query or my Tree Node Model to include Grand-Children and Great-Grand-Children

Tags: c#, tree, entity-framework-core

I have an Entity Model that is basically a Tree Node:

```
[Table("bma_ec_categories")]
public class Category : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] 
    [Column("category_id")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    [Column("parent_category_id")]
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("category_name")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Category Parent { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Category> Children { get; set; }
    
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

In my DbContext I have:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Parent)
            .WithMany(c => c.Children)
            .HasForeignKey(k => k.ParentId);
```

I have one query that uses `Category`:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<EcommerceItemDto>> GetAllItemsAsync(User user, string category = "All", int page = 0, int pageSize = 9999)
    {
        IQueryable<Category> categories;

        if (category == "All")
        {
            categories = _context.Categories
                .Include(c => c.Children)
                .Include(p => p.Parent)
                .AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution();

        }
        else
        {
            categories = _context.Categories
                .Where(n => n.Name == category)
                .Include(c => c.Children)
                .Include(p => p.Parent)
                .AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution();
        }

        var p1 = new SqlParameter("@Custnmbr", SqlDbType.Char, 15) {Value = user.Custnmbr};
        var dto = await _context.EcommerceItems
            .FromSqlRaw($"SELECT * FROM [cp].[GetEcommerceItemsView] WHERE [CustomerNumber] = @Custnmbr",p1)
            .Include(x => x.Category)
            .Include(i => i.Images.OrderByDescending(d => d.Default))
            .OrderBy(i => i.ItemNumber)
            .Where(c => categories.Contains(c.Category) || categories.Any(x => x.Children.Contains(c.Category)))
            .Skip(page * pageSize)
            .Take(pageSize)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ProjectTo<EcommerceItemDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
            .ToListAsync();

        return dto;
    }
```

No problems if the method is called with the default of "All", however if an actual Category Name is used  I only will be getting the one `Parent` and the immediate `Children`. What can I do to change my query or my Model to include `Grand-Children` and `Great-Grand-Children` *etc*?

**UPDATE**

I was asked to add my `EcommerceItemDto` Model:

```
public class EcommerceItemDto
{
    [Key]
    public string ItemNumber { get; set; }

    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "text")]
    public string ExtendedDesc { get; set; }

    public bool? Featured { get; set; }

    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "numeric(19, 5)")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    
    [Column(TypeName = "numeric(19, 5)")]
    public decimal QtyOnHand { get; set; }        

    public ICollection<EcommerceItemImagesDto> Images { get; set; }
}
```

I have twenty or so metadata properties that I didn't include to save space.

Comment: A I know, when using ProjectTo, all includes are ignored. Also query result will be never tracked. Try to write effective query without Automapper, then fight with configuration.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I am sorry but, I am afraid your statement about "all includes are ignored" is incorrect. Would you mind telling me why my query is not "effective"?

Comment: I know that, because ProjectTo generates custom projection. And when you use custom projection EF Core ignores Includes. Includes are needed when you select whole entities.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv The returned results from the query include images AND the sql in the cached query plan on the sql server is using the Categories to filter. We are going to have to agree to disagree.

Comment: Can you add `EcommerceItemDto` to the question?

Comment: Well, I see your problem. You have to create Table Valued Stored procedure which uses recursive CTE for grabbing child record in trees. There a lot of answers how to do that on SO. EF Core itself do not support CTE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a comment from @SvyatoslavDanyliv, I found this web [article](https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/recursive-data-with-entity-framework-core-and-sql-server). Using it as an example, I added this to my DbContext:

```
public Task<List<Category>> AllChildren(string category) =>
        Categories.FromSqlRaw(
                @"WITH organization (category_id, category_name, title, parent_category_id, below) AS (
                            SELECT category_id, category_name, title, parent_category_id, 0
                            FROM dbo.bma_ec_categories    
                            WHERE bma_ec_categories.category_name = {0}         
                            UNION ALL
                    SELECT
                        e.category_id
                       ,e.category_name
                       ,e.title
                       ,e.parent_category_id
                       ,o.below + 1
                    FROM dbo.bma_ec_categories e
                    INNER JOIN organization o
                        ON o.category_id = e.parent_category_id)
                    SELECT * FROM organization", category)
            .AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution()
            .ToListAsync();
```

I changed my query to:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<EcommerceItemDto>> GetAllItemsAsync(User user, string category = "All", int page = 0, int pageSize = 9999)
    {
        List<Category> categories;

        if (category == "All")
        {
            categories = await _context.Categories
                .AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution()
                .ToListAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            categories = await _context.AllChildren(category);
        }

        var p1 = new SqlParameter("@Custnmbr", SqlDbType.Char, 15) {Value = user.Custnmbr};
        var dto = await _context.EcommerceItems
            .FromSqlRaw($"SELECT * FROM [cp].[GetEcommerceItemsView] WHERE [CustomerNumber] = @Custnmbr",p1)
            .Include(x => x.Category)
            .Include(i => i.Images.OrderByDescending(d => d.Default))
            .OrderBy(i => i.ItemNumber)
            .Where(c => categories.Contains(c.Category))
            .Skip(page * pageSize)
            .Take(pageSize)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ProjectTo<EcommerceItemDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
            .ToListAsync();

        return dto;
    }
```

Everything is working now and I am happy.