# Why is EF Core adding an extra ORDER BY on the end

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a query:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<CategoryDto>> GetCategoriesAsync()
    {
        var dto = await _context.Categories.FromSqlRaw(
                @"SELECT * FROM [cp].[GetCategoryTree]")
            .ProjectTo<CategoryDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
            .AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution()
            .ToListAsync();

        return dto;
    }
```

It produces this sql:

```sql
SELECT [c].[banner_group_id], [c].[category_id], [c].[description], [c].[inactive], [c].[issitecategory], [c].[keywords], [c].[category_name], [c].[page_content], [c].[parent_category_id], [c].[sort_order], [c].[title], [b].[banner_group_id], [b].[category_id], [b].[description], [b].[inactive], [b].[issitecategory], [b].[keywords], [b].[category_name], [b].[page_content], [b].[parent_category_id], [b].[sort_order], [b].[title]

FROM (

    SELECT * FROM [cp].[GetCategoryTree]

) AS [c]

LEFT JOIN [bma_ec_categories] AS [b] ON [c].[category_id] = [b].[parent_category_id]

ORDER BY [c].[category_id], [b].[category_id]
```

The output from `[cp].[GetCategoryTree]` is already sorted in that view. Why is EF Core adding an extra `ORDER BY` on the end? Can I tell EF Core to not sort?

Comment: Odd...is it Automapper's ProjectTo? Can you remove that and log your query?

Comment: @GHDevOps Yep, that's what was doing it.

Comment: Mapping to `CategoryDto` causes the join and I see that when EF-core joins it always adds ordering by PK values, probably to make post processing easier (building the objects in memory).

Comment: Views have no ordering, what do you mean it's already sorted?

Comment: @Charlieface they can if you use `TOP`

Comment: No they cannot, that is simply a hack to be able to put the words `ORDER BY` in the view, it only means that the `TOP` is evaluated after sorting, it *does not* and I repeat **DOES NOT** enforce any sorting on the outer query, it's a complete myth. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/15188437/14868997 and https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4488/avoid-order-by-in-sql-server-views/ and https://bengribaudo.com/blog/2015/05/01/3430/t-sql-ordering-myth-2-order-by-in-views and https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/21437/220697

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive CTE returns result is plain recordset, it means that if you need tree on the client side, you have to reconstruct it by yourself.

Let's reuse original query:

```cs
public async Task<IEnumerable<CategoryDto>> GetCategoriesAsync()
{
    var plainResult = await _context.Categories.FromSqlRaw(@"SELECT * FROM [cp].[GetCategoryTree]")
        .Select(c => new CategoryDto
        {
            CategoryId = c.CategoryId,
            ParentId = c.ParentId,
            Name = c.Name,
            SortOrder = c.SortOrder
        })
        .ToListAsync();

       var lookup = plainResult.Where(x => x.ParentId != 0).ToLookup(x => x.ParentId);

       foreach (c in plainResult)
       {
           if (lookup.ContainsKey(c.CategoryId))
           {
               c.Children = lookup[c.CategoryId]
                   .OrderBy(x => x.SortOrder)
                   .ThenBy(x => x.Name)
                   .ToList();
           }            
       }

    var dto = plainResult.Where(x => x.ParentId == 0).ToList();

    return dto;
}
```

Comment: Actually I do not see here why do you need Recursive CTE. You can make original query directly from `_context.Categories`.  CTE is needed if you want to select leaf of the Tree.

Answer (score 0):

I started out with a flat `Category` query. I needed it to be in a Tree Structure. So I added an `Include` for the `Children`. But it only included children on the root elements. I asked on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68628928/how-can-i-change-my-query-or-my-tree-node-model-to-include-grand-children-and-gr) and was pointed to a `Recursive CTE`. That's what `[cp].[GetCategoryTree]` is. I now have scrapped all that and made my query:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<CategoryDto>> GetCategoriesAsync()
    {
       var dto = await _context.Categories
            .Where(x => x.ParentId == 0)
            .OrderBy(x=> x.SortOrder)
            .ThenBy(x => x.Name)
            .ProjectTo<CategoryDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ToListAsync();

       foreach (var categoryDto in dto)
       {
           foreach (var categoryDtoChild in categoryDto.Children)
           {
               categoryDtoChild.Children = await _context.Categories
                   .Where(x => x.ParentId == categoryDtoChild.CategoryId)
                   .OrderBy(x => x.SortOrder)
                   .ThenBy(x => x.Name)
                   .ProjectTo<CategoryDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
                   .AsNoTracking()
                   .ToListAsync();
            }
       }

        return dto;
    }
```

Which works, slowly sure, But populates all the way down to Great-Grand-Child. If anyone has a better solution, I am all ears.

Benchmark Results(Mine and @SvyatoslavDanyliv):

| Method | IterationCount | Mean | Error | StdDev | Median | Min | Max | Ratio | RatioSD | Gen 0 | Gen 1 | Gen 2 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GetCategories | 1 | 142.82 ms | 5.260 ms | 14.921 ms | 142.65 ms | 85.572 ms | 170.29 ms | 1.00 | 0.00 | 1000.0000 | - | - | 5,845 KB |
| GetCategoriesSingleQuery | 1 | 11.17 ms | 0.501 ms | 1.396 ms | 10.87 ms | 8.057 ms | 14.76 ms | 0.08 | 0.01 | - | - | - | 914 KB |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| GetCategories | 2 | 290.03 ms | 7.703 ms | 21.473 ms | 288.38 ms | 239.879 ms | 350.48 ms | 1.00 | 0.00 | 2000.0000 | - | - | 11,637 KB |
| GetCategoriesSingleQuery | 2 | 23.21 ms | 1.815 ms | 5.207 ms | 21.58 ms | 17.005 ms | 38.73 ms | 0.08 | 0.02 | - | - | - | 1,745 KB |

I think I will accept @SvyatoslavDanyliv's answer.

Comment: Why not by single query?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Please, give me an Example for a single query.

Comment: I have added another answer.